# Esperar un tiempo en una function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta function

```
function cambiosIngenieria(){

            var devuelto = vm.productosGridOptions.dataSource.data();
            var idDetallelinea;
            devuelto.forEach(function (lineaDevuelto) {
                if (lineaDevuelto.RevisionIngenieria == "Devuelto") {
                    console.log("Es para devolver");
                    idDetallelinea = lineaDevuelto.Id;
                    var _revisionIngenieria = {
                        __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.DetalleLineasListItem' },
                    }
                    _revisionIngenieria.RevisionIngenieria = "Pendiente"
                    var context = getContext("../lists/DetalleLineas");
                    var resultFecha = updateItem("../_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('DetalleLineas')/getItemById(" + idDetallelinea + ")", context, _revisionIngenieria);
                    //vm.productosGridOptions.dataSource.read()
                }
            });
            vm.productosGridOptions.dataSource.read()

        }
```

Lo que hace es traerme un array de un grid de `Kendo UI` y actualizar un dato en una lista de sharepoint.

Ahora lo que necesito realizar en la  function `cambiosIngenieria` esperar 5 segundos mientras `vm.productosGridOptions.dataSource.read()` termina de actualizar el grid y luego seguir con el proceso.

Alguna forma de realizarlo.

Comment: Haz probado usar `setTimeout()` ?

Comment: Y porqué tienes que esperar 5 segundos? que te devuelve dataSource.read() ? Lo de esperar 5 segundos no tiene sentido.

Comment: El método read no admite una función callback?

Comment: creo que tu enfoque de esperar un tiempo fijo es una malisima idea, deberias de poder disparar algun evento cuando termine, mas que poner esperar un tiempo N

Comment: podrías probar, encerrar tu problema dentro de una promesa , para que que trabajes cuando se resuelva , osea cuando termine y no tengas que ponerle un tiempo fijo , esa no es la forma correcta de hacer ese tipo de operaciones

Comment: Tenían razón lo solucione con el callback, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segun la [documentacion](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/read) de `read()` lo retornado es una promesa.

Asi que puedes seguir ejecutando tu codigo cuando esta finaliza, como lo ponen en el ejemplo:

```
dataSource.read().then(function() {
  var view = dataSource.view();
  console.log(view[0].ProductName); // displays "Chai"
});
```